# how to access an aggregated views field?

Tags: views

I have a view with one field called production hours.

I have several rows in this view but have used the sum aggregation setting.

The only value I get is the total of all the values in the field production hour.

Im now trying to access that total value via php.

So I add header, if I select text area I can use the field using tokens, but if I try and insert that token into php code nothing happens.

All I want to do is get the sum of field production hours and output the total but convert it to days instead of hours.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You should be able to use the rewrite output option for the field. From your question and use of tokens you may have already tried this. If you have and it is not working perhaps a screen shot will help figure out why.

Comment: Try another approach. Look at [Views hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7), select the correct one (post query, pre-render), and try to apply your alteration to the field there.